# Why Authenticated user not able to submit webform and only admin can submit?

Tags: 8, webforms

I am creating a webform with just two fields and displaying it on modal popup with Ajax submit. But the issue I am facing is, this webform can only be submitted by Administer role user not by authenticated user. For authenticated user form will display but when they click on submit it will show a Ajax popup error.

[image]

I checked in webform configurations access settings and permissions settings also. But I didn't find out a solution. Can anyone help in this regard.

**Edit:** I guess its a modal popup issue. Because when I directly access a webform for authenticated user, I can able to submit a form successfully. Since this webform I am displaying this in a modal popup while submitting I am getting Ajax error for authenticated user.

Comment: Please paste error messages as text, don't add them as screenshot, as they are difficult to read or copy, especially on mobile. Does this `$form.ajaxSubmit` say you anything? And are there any other unrelated JS errors in the console? Then you need to fix them first. We'd also need to see your modal popup Ajax code, if any. Please edit your question accordingly. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As its showing in Ajax popup there is no console errors, and not able to make it in a text format. So do you think that there is no specific configuration for role based restriction of webform submission?

Comment: Check the error log `/admin/reports/dblog` perhaps it will show a more helpful error message there.

Comment: @NoSssweat, I checked dblog also, there also not logging any errors. I just updated the question, as it looks like modal popup issue.

Comment: We don't know how this modal got there or if there's any custom code that can be fixed. Is there any code you can show? I asked for that in my opening comment already.